# keyup event not fired on tinyMCE 4.1.8

Tags: tinymce-4

I can't get the keyup event fired. My code is:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    paste_as_text: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists charmap preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime nonbreaking",
        "directionality paste textcolor"
    ],
    menubar:false,
    statusbar:true,
    toolbar: "bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | removeformat | forecolor backcolor | bullist numlist | hr | charmap",

    setup : function(ed) {

        ed.on('init', function() {
            console.log('Perfectly works ');

          });

        ed.on('keyup', function(ed, evt) {

            console.log('Never called ');
        });
    },
});
```

As explained in the code it perfectly executes the function associated to `init` event, I don't see any error in the console but when I hit keys in the editor the function associated to `keyup` is not calld.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing the keyup function works fine in TinyMCE 4.1.8 - see this attached TinyMCE Fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/JGfaab/2

Key up is processed each time in both Chrome and Safari when testing on a Mac.